# Preserving PAREN! when a reduce operation is run on a block

Tags: rebol, operator-precedence, dialect

When you use REDUCE you basically operate in the DO dialect, where PAREN! groups can be used for precedence on items:

```
>> reduce ["Hello" (3 + 4) * 5]
== ["Hello" 35]
```

While in the COMPOSE dialect, PAREN! is used to call out which parts of the block you want to evaluate with the DO dialect, leaving the rest alone:

```
>> compose ["Hello" (3 + 4) * 5]
== ["Hello" 7 * 5]
```

But if you want to run reduce or compose and have a few things you want to leave in as literal parentheses, is there another idiom for it besides `to-paren` and a block?

```
>> reduce ["Hello" (3 + 4) * 5 to-paren ["inside!"]]
== ["Hello" 35 ("inside")]
```

*Sidenote: I wonder what sort of craziness would result from LIT-PAREN?*

```
>> reduce ["Hello" (3 + 4) * 5 '("inside!")]
== ["Hello" 35 ("inside")]
```

*...then again, I don't know that I want to think about it.  :-)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The more general way to achieve what you want is to rely on `quote`:

```
>> reduce ["Hello " (3 + 4) * 5 quote ("inside!")]
== ["Hello " 35 ("inside!")]
```

QUOTE is available in R3 and in R2 since 2.7.7.

Comment: It sometimes seems silly to ask these things when you know *some way* to do it, but then you find better idioms...

Answer (score 2):

Another idiom, yes:

```
>> reduce ["Hello" (3 + 4) * 5 first [("inside!")]]
== ["Hello" 35 ("inside")]
```

Not sure it's any better, but it is a *different* animal.

Comment: Well, it's one fewer character and makes the fact that parenthesized code is in there more evident to the reader.  A block with nothing but one paren group in it calls attention to itself.  So this is better, I think...although it has more overhead in terms of the symbol structure: `first, [], (), ""` vs `to-paren, [], ""`

Comment: D'oh, forgot that one—and I'd just had a discussion on quote as well!